# understanding semaphore

Tags: semaphore

I am a mechanical eng student  and I can't understand how they could arrive at this solution for the following question. It would of real help to me if someone could help me in understanding, as to how they got to a solution like this.

Given are two processes P1 and P2  accessing the shared resource ShR. Use semaphores to ensure a cyclic access order of P1, P1, P2 (i.e. P1, P1, P2 (First cycle), P1, P1, P2 (second cycle), ...) to ShR. You should also give initial values for the used.

Solution to this problem is :

```
/* semaphore initialization */
init (S1,2)
init (S2,0)

/* process P1 */
loop
    wait(S1)
    access(ShR);
    signal(S2)
end loop;

/* process P2 */ 
loop
    wait(S2)
    wait(S2)
    access(ShR);
    signal(S1)
    signal(S1)
end loop;
```

Answer (score 2):

A [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) is used to limit simultaneous access to a resource. If, say, I want 500 people to enter a club, I can have a list of who is going in and out.

This is equivalent to the semaphore `up()` and `down()` (in your code it's `signal()` and `wait()`.

Say our semaphore is the bouncer:

We will initialize it by calling `init (Bouncer, 500)`

A person entering the club would make the bouncer call it's `wait(Bouncer)` method, making one less room available.

A person leaving the club would make the bouncer call it's `signal(Bouncer)` method, making one more room available.

When the Bouncer calls 500 more `wait`s than `signal`s, there is no room in the club and no one can go in.

In your problem:

```
/* semaphore initialization */
1. init (S1,2); /* make two rooms available for P1 in shared resource */
2. init (S2,0); /* make no room for P2 */

/* process P1 */
1. loop
1.1. wait(S1); /* make one less room available for P1 */
1.2. access(ShR); /* access resource... */
1.3. signal(S2) /* make one more room for p2 */
1. end loop;

/* process P2 */
1. loop
1.1. wait(S2); /* wait for room to clear for P2 on resource */
1.2. wait(S2); /* wait for room to clear for P2 on resource */
1.3. access(ShR); /* access resource... */
1.4. signal(S1); /* make one more room to P1 */
1.5. signal(S1); /* make one more room to P1 */
1. end loop;
```

These loops will unfold in this sequence (let's say we start in **init-state**):

loop for P1 iterates twice, because it has two permits to access to resource to begin with.

loop for P2 **waits** twice, (`wait` called twice on start of loop) and reaches 1.3 only after loop for P1 happens twice (two resource accesses for p1? check!)

then loop for P1 must wait for a signal from loop for P2, which is on 1.4 and 1.5. These two signals allow for two more accesses to loop for P1, which "resets" the system to **init-state**, in practice, thus meeting the exercise criteria (just loop through my explanation again, and again... then eat some ice-cream)

**IMPORTANT:**
The loops do not necessarily unfold in this particular sequence, but the explanation should be sufficient to understand the program flow. Loop for P2 can't access the resource before it gets two `signal`s from two loop of P1, and loop 1 can't re-iterate before two `signal`s from Loop for P1.